# Using the this ptr in a constexpr expression

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

I have two types, one for define `Natural` numbers (*positive integers >= 1*) and other for define Integers (any whole numerical value, or integer).

Trying to implement the `operator-(const Natural rhs)`, I would like to return an Integer instead of a Natural if the subtraction value is < 1. So this is my attempt:

```
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto Natural::operator-(const Natural& rhs) const noexcept
    -> std::conditional_t<(_number > rhs.number() + 1), Natural, Integer>
{
    if constexpr(_number > rhs.number() + 1)
        return Natural(_number - rhs.number());
    else
        return Integer(static_cast<int>(_number) - static_cast<int>(rhs.number()));
}
```

But *Clang-Tidy* is telling me that is not allowed the use of the implicit *this* ptr in the constexpr branch, because the value is not known at compile time.
That makes all the sense, but I don't know how to solve this situation with other tools than SFINAE, which I am trying to avoid because is usage is more complicated and the codebase should be the simpler as possible.

So, is there any way where I can solve this, and be able to discard one of the branches at compile time?

Note: Natural type is just a wrapper over an `unsigned int`

Comment: C++ provides no special way to determine the return type of a function from the value of its arguments. Return type can only depend on template arguments.

Comment: This is a fundamental problem all compiling languages have, which defines the way they deal with argument promotion and underflow\overflow.

Comment: The only way is to write a type-level implementation of the integers and arithmetic. A type can't depend on any runtime value.

Comment: Even if defining return type based on values of function arguments were possible at all (it isn't), it would only make sense for `consteval` (whose evaluation is only possible at compile time and where values of arguments are always known at compile time) functions, not `constexpr` ones (which can be called both at runtime at compile time).

Comment: You're tyring to mix a runtime calculated value with a selection that has to be determined at compile time. If you want anything close to this you might need to return a `std::variant<Natural,Integer>` . But this will not make the rest of the code easier.